# Performance issue with my query.Please suggest

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, query-optimization, oracle11g

```
MERGE INTO Analysis a
USING ( SELECT * FROM  Data ) b
ON ( a.User_Id = b.User_Id AND a.Upgrade_Flag = 0 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET Status = NVL(a.Status, 'ACTIVATE');
```

The above query works fine.But when millions of records are present this may lead to performance issue.Is there any alternative for the above query to get a better performace.Please suggest me on this.Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you show us an execution plan for the statement?

Comment: Performance tuning is a matter of evidence gathering.  So you need to provide way more information.  Data volumes for both tables, distribution of data, which columns are indexed.  Also explain plans for the query, and statistics too.  Also indicative timings including what you think ought to be a reasonable time.  Finally, context:is this a regular job or a one-off?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the execution plans I can't predict whether an alternative would be any more efficient.  But I note that you are not using the merge source in the update, which indicates that this could rewritten as a simple update statement:

```
UPDATE Analysis a
SET Status = NVL(a.Status, 'ACTIVATE')
WHERE a.Upgrade_Flag = 0
AND a.User_Id IN (
  SELECT b.User_Id FROM Data b
)
```

As is always the case with these things, you have a choice between using an `IN` clause, as I have shown, or an `EXISTS` clause with a correlated subquery.  Usually it's worth testing both options when trying to tune performance, although in at least some cases the optimizer will try that transformation on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The query looks fine to me. Maybe you should create some indexes?

Create index for Analysis.User_Id and index for Data.User_Id if not yet created (primary key creates index automatically).

Or maybe also create index for Analysis containing both columns User_Id and Upgrade_Flag.

Comment: Juho:@peter Index already created.But still,Can it lead to performace issues at any time since there trillions of records?

Answer (score 0):

It's really not at all obvious why you are using MERGE instead of a simple UPDATE.

```
update analysis a
set a.status = 'ACTIVATE'
where a.status is null
and a.upgrade_flag = 0 
and a.user_id in ( select b.user_id from  data b )
/
```

Selecting only the USER_ID from DATA instead of the entire record could speed things up, presuming DATA.USER_ID is indexed.